# How can I tell if a Youtube video cannot be viewed with Restricted Mode enabled?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Using the youtube Data API - videos: For a few videos using contentDetails.contentRating.ytRating shows that the video is ytAgeRestricted.

However most videos blocked in restricted mode do not have a contentRating in the JSON. E.g.:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=contentDetails&id=vBkBS4O3yvY&key={API_KEY}
```

Only the following is returned:

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#videoListResponse",
 "etag": "\"abQHWywil_AkNqdqji7_FqiK-u4/MGunVBb8A5UKg1uOrK7QknvhVZ8\"",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 1,
  "resultsPerPage": 1
 },
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "youtube#video",
   "etag": "\"abQHWywil_AkNqdqji7_FqiK-u4/n1iZ1JVdolHHrm8Nd2wvTRcfe5s\"",
   "id": "vBkBS4O3yvY",
   "contentDetails": {
    "duration": "PT5M41S",
    "dimension": "2d",
    "definition": "hd",
    "caption": "false",
    "licensedContent": true
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

Comment: The video with id `vBkBS4O3yvY` is not age restricted.

Comment: Are you perhaps looking for a corresponding response property that has name like "restricted" or something? Then will have true if cannot be seen in restricted mode and false otherwise? Because if that's the case then there is none that's stated in the documentation. "While it's not 100 percent accurate, we use community flagging, age-restrictions, and other signals to identify and filter out inappropriate content." is what stated in the documentation as the criteria for restricted mode, but maybe you can file it as a feature request.